# Cannot run ECharts Demo locally

Tags: echarts

After I download the following ECharts demo, and open it in my browser (Safari or Chrome), it keeps showing it is loading, and the demo will never start. How do I make this demo work locally for me?

Link: https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=graph

Comment: did you clone the repo and build it?

Comment: I have just downloaded the example by clicking the Download button on the bottom right corner.
Do you mean building the repo with `npm` and `echarts/build/build.js`  as described in https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/tutorial.html#Create%20Custom%20Build%20of%20ECharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways cause it keeps loading, I guess your problem is caused by loading data resource failed.

There is an `ajax` in this [demo](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=graph)

```
$.get('data/asset/data/les-miserables.gexf', function() { ...
```

If you didn't change the resource URL, function `$.get` run failed so the statement `myChart.hideLoading();` didn't execute that why it keeps loading

You should change url `data/asset/data/les-miserables.gexf` to `https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/data/asset/data/les-miserables.gexf`

There is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IanZhong/h5v3ps1c/69/)

Comment: Thanks Ian. I actually managed to make this work using the jsfiddle you provided!

Comment: @Endre glad to help  ;)